# Who are the next-generation (Cursed Child) Hogwarts teachers/staff?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, the-cursed-child

In *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, we know that very few teachers remain at Hogwarts from Harry's days there. Who are the new Hogwarts teachers? I do not own a copy of the book, so I can't look directly. I know that Neville Longbottom now teaches Herbology. Who are the rest of the new teachers/staff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Prime timeline - The teachers we know about are**

- McGonagall- Headmistress.
- Neville- Herbology.
- Madam Hooch- Flying.
- Hagrid- Groundskeeper, Care of Magical Creatures (he isn't mentioned as a teacher in Cursed Child but in "*19 years later*" he is.)

**In the second timeline**

- Hermione is added as DADA.

**In the third timeline we only know about**

- Snape - Potions
- Umbridge- Headmistress.

**All timelines - teachers that probably stayed**

- Professor Binns
- Flitwick.

Comment: I've played with the formatting a little in order to make the answer more readable. You might also want to consider adding some supporting quotes.

Comment: I haven't read the play script yet but what is this about timelines? Is time travel/splitting timelines a major plot point of the play?

Comment: @TylerH Yes. The main plot of the play is having next generation Hogwarts students exploring (and interfering with) alternative timelines in the past.

Answer (score -3):

1. Headmistress-Professor Minerva McGonagall
2. History of Magic-Professor Cuthbert Binns
3. Muggle Studies-Unknown (possibly Arabella Figg or Arhtur Weasley)
4. Charms-Professor Filius Flitwick
5. Flying-Madam Rolanda Hooch
6. Potions Master-Professor Horace Slughorn
7. Care for Magical Creatures-Professor Rubeus Hagrid
8. Herbology-Professor Neville Longbottom
9. Divination-Professor Firenze and Professor Sybill Trelawney
10. Defense Against the Dark Arts-Professor Hermoine Jean Granger-Weasley
11. Astronomy-Professor Aurora Sinestra
12. Arithmancy-Professor Septima Vector
13. Ancient Runes-??? (No idea!)
14. Alchemy-??? (wasn't even mentioned in the first place!!)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What are your sources for this?

Answer (score -4):

1. History of magic-Professor Binn
2. Muggle Studies-Professor Charity Burbage
3. Charms-Professor Flitwick
4. Flying-Professor Hooch
5. Potions-Professor Horce Slughorn
6. Care of Magical Creatures-Professor Hadrig
7. Herbology-Professor Hannah Abbot [Neville's wife]
8. Divination-Professor Trelawney
9. Defence Dark Art Magic-Professor Amycus Carrow

***Read Harry Potter and the Cursed Child u will get it***

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you provide any references for these?

Comment: Didn't Burbage run into You Know Who in DH?

Comment: I have read Cursed Child, but it's been a while. Also, I believe that Charity was fed to Nagini in Deathly Hallows. Welcome to the site tho! A general rule here is to cite references/source material when offering an answer, and research first. That's alright though, everyone had a first time!